# How to Print an array with names

Tags: c

I wrote this code to input names to array (eg:Jon,raj...) and the input part is ok but how to print exact name that i input to this array a[5] why this code is not working

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>



int main(){

    int i;
    char a[5];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Enter  ");
        scanf("%s",&a[i]);
     }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s \n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try compiling with all warnings.

Comment: If the output isn't what it should be, how do you know that the input part is ok?

Comment: In the statement: `scanf("%s",&a[i]);`, the format code `%s` is expecting to process an array of `char` into a string.  But `&a[i]` is a ingle character.  Two suggestions; 1) make `a` bigger unless you really want to limit user input to only 4 `char`, eg char a[80];` maybe, 2) If you are going to use `scanf`, then call it like this:  `scanf("%s",a);`  Same issue with the `print` statement.

Comment: `char a[5]` is not an array of 5 strings but an array of 5 characters which can hold a string of 4 characters plus a trailing NUL (`'\0'`) character. If you enter a longer string your input will write past the end of the array. Your 2nd input will overwrite the part from the 2nd character of the 1st string. etc ...

Comment: Your down-votes are likely because you asked a question, and have been silent since.  No feedback, no responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your array *a* is an array of chars. This means that in each position you will have only one char.

You can do this any one of these two ways:

---

1. Pre-allocated (array of arrays of chars)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int NAME_MAXIMUM_SIZE = 50;
    const int NUMBER_OF_NAMES = 5;
    int index;
    char names [NUMBER_OF_NAMES][NAME_MAXIMUM_SIZE];
    for(index=0; index<NUMBER_OF_NAMES; index++){
        printf("Enter  ");
        scanf("%49s",names[index]);
     }
    for(index=0; index<NUMBER_OF_NAMES; index++){
        printf("%s \n",names[index]);
    }
}
```

---

2. Malloc + free (array of pointers)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    const int NAME_MAXIMUM_SIZE = 50;
    const int NUMBER_OF_NAMES = 5;
    int index;
    char *names [NUMBER_OF_NAMES];
    for(index=0; index<NUMBER_OF_NAMES; index++){
        names[index] = (char*)malloc(NAME_MAXIMUM_SIZE);
        printf("Enter  ");
        scanf("%49s",names[index]);
     }
    for(index=0; index<NUMBER_OF_NAMES; index++){
        printf("%s \n",names[index]);
        free(names[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"...wrote this code to input names to array..."*

`char a[5]` does not create 5 [C strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm).  It is simply an array of 5 `char`.  It provides room for only ***1***, 4 character *C string* (leaving room for the `\0` terminator).  If you need an *array* of names, of typical size the code will need an *array* of *arrays* each with space sufficient for typical names.  For example:

```
char a[5][80] = {{0}}; //provides an array capable of containing 5 names
```

Also, in the *read* statement: `scanf("%s",&a[i]);`, the format code `%s` is expecting to process an array of `char`.  But is provided with `&a[i]` which is only a single character.  If you are going to use `scanf`, then call it like this:  `scanf("%s",a);`  Same issue with the `print` statement.

Make the following edits to address these basic issues:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char a[5][80] = {{0}};//space for 5 names, each with up to 79 characters
                          //arrays are initialized to zeros

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)//sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) is flexible way to 
                                         //loop only through number of names.  
                                         //If array size changes, expression will still work
    {
        printf("Enter name %d:\n ", i+1);
        scanf("%79s",a[i]);//limit input to prevent overflow
        //      ^^
     }
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a[0])/sizeof(a[0][0]);i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 2 dimensional array. Here your variable a which is a character array stores only one character at each index.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>



     int main(){

     int i;
     char a[5];

     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("Enter  ");
        scanf("%s",&a[i]);
     }
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s \n",a[i]);
     }
   }
```